# Applying a predicate to a joined table

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, expression

I am trying to use a predicate on a joined table but I don't know how to formulate it.  An example will explain the issue best.

I have two tables:

- `User` table (`ID int`, `Name varchar(64)`, `Email varchar(128)`, `Active bit`)
- `Event` table (`ID int`, `Date datetime(2)`, `UserID int` (foreign key), `Description varchar(max)`)

A user can have zero to many events and an event is associated with exactly one user (via the foreign key).

Now I have a bunch of `User` predicates:

```
Expression<Func<User, bool>> nameIsBob = u => u.Name == "Bob";
Expression<Func<User, bool>> isActive = u => u.Active;
```

which I can apply when querying the `User` table:

```
var query1 = ctx.Users.Where(nameIsBob ).Select(u => u);
var query2 = ctx.Users.Where(isActive).Select(u => u);
```

However, if I start with a list of `Events` and want to filter only those events belonging to certain users, I want to do something like this but I cannot work out the syntax:

```
var query3 = ctx.Events
    .Where(e => e.User(nameIsBob))
    .Select(e => new { e.EventID, e.User.UserID });
```

The issue is the 2nd line where the predicate cannot be wrapped around `e.User`. I've also tried:

```
var query4 = ctx.Events
    .Where(e => e.User.Where(nameIsBob))
    .Select(e => new { e.EventID, e.User.UserID });
```

Any advice on how I can get *all events that belong to people named Bob*? (and there may be multiple users called Bob).  I can't really start with the User table as the examples above are much simplified versions of what I'm doing (and I hope I'm not describing an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this wasn't database backed but instead simple client side entities, you could compile your Expression you can use it like a method that takes a User and returns a bool:

```
Expression<Func<User, bool>> nameIsBob = u => u.Name == "Bob";

Func<User, bool> compiledNamedIsBob = nameIsBob.Compile();

var query3 = something.Events
    .Where(e => compiledNameIsBob(e.User))
```

This would be taking your `Expression<Func<User, bool>>`, taking the `Func<User, bool>` out of it and creating an `Expression<Func<Event, bool>>` where the `Func<Event, bool>` pulls the event User out and calls the `Func<User, bool>` using it..

**IMPORTANT**: this advice to compile an Expression to a Func flat out doesn't work on something like entity framework. EF will take the written .NET Expression and translate it into SQL, and though it can be quite clever at doing so, it won't take a self contained .NET method (acquired from compiling an Expression to a Func, above) and pick it apart, translating its constituent statements to SQL. The only way it could work out would be to download the entire DB table into the client, then call the .NET method on every downloaded record (unless work was done to have EF send the .NET method to SQLServer, compile it there and call it as part of the query. .NET functions can exist in SQL Server, but EF doesn't do this)

---

#### So...

You need to appreciate that `ctx.Events.Where()` takes an `Expression<Func<Event, bool>>` and you have an `Expression<Func<User, bool>>` -> you need to make an Expression that works with Events:

```
Expression<Func<Event, bool>> eventUserNameIsBob = e => e.User.Name == "Bob";
```

Which you could also do for Event like you did for User:

```
//like you did this
Expression<Func<User, bool>> nameIsBob = u => u.Name == "Bob";
Expression<Func<User, bool>> isActive = u => u.Active;

//you can do this
Expression<Func<Event, bool>> eventUserNameIsBob = e => e.User.Name == "Bob");
```

And apply like you apply to the user table:

```
var query1 = ctx.Users.Where(nameIsBob); //returns Users
var query2 = ctx.Users.Where(isActive); //returns Users
var query3 = ctx.Events.Where(eventUserNameIsBob).Select(e => e.User); //returns Users, via the Select
```

However, if you only want to have the `nameIsBob` expression, not the `eventUserNameIsBob` expression you need to appreciate that the `nameIsBob` expression *only works on queryable collections Users* so you have to take all your events and dig the users out of them, and run the expression on the dug out Users, which means you've essentially lost knowledge of your Event (you have to get it back by asking the User):

```
var query4 = ctx.Events.Select(e => e.User).Where(nameIsBob);
```

This *does* return you "a bunch of users" like the other queries do (`ctx.Users.Where(nameIsBob)`), but you've lost the event unless you get it back via the user:

```
var query4 = ctx.Events.Select(e => e.User).Where(nameIsBob).Select(u => u.Event);
```

What your DB will do in this case, I'm not sure; you'd have to test it/log the generated SQL.

Personally I would make a new expression that understands events as per above (`eventUserNameIsBob`) or I wouldn't bother passing expressions around and I would simply define them inline:

```
var query3 = ctx.Events.Where(e => e.User.Name == "Bob"); //events owned by bobs
```

Modern DB ORMs can unpack this to become `SELECT events.* FROM events JOIN users ON (...) WHERE users.name = 'bob'` rather than in days of old where it would be like:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = 'bob' --returns list of 1,2,4,5
SELECT * FROM events WHERE userid = 1
SELECT * FROM events WHERE userid = 2
SELECT * FROM events WHERE userid = 4
SELECT * FROM events WHERE userid = 5
```

Comment: That's great.  And thanks for the explanation of Expressions vs Functions.  The rationale for predefining my expressions is that the expression is actually passed in from the caller based on external factors.  The advise you've given works so thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'm banking on the fact that the query will compile to SQL as an (inner) join rather than selecting a list of User IDs and then performing a second (or multiple) queries on Events where `UserID = ` or `UserID IN`. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I thought that this would resolve my issue, except this raises the Exception "Invoke is not supported in Linq to Entities". at runtime.  :-(

Comment: Ah.. Yes, sorry. That was a bad advice by me.. At the time I'd written the first part I'd skipped over the point that the LINQ expression undergoes a transformation to SQL, and there's no way that a .NET method can be translated to SQL (well.. It could be created and called in an SQL server, but ORMs don't do that)

Comment: OK, I made an edit to give some hopefully better advice for this context (pun not intended!)

Comment: Thanks @Caius for the update.  I implemented the 2nd option (new expression `eventUserNameIsBob` that understands Users from the Events entity).  I might try the "resellect events" to see how the SQL is generated.  However, my money is that it won't be a simple join but a more clumbersome `SELECT Event where UserID IN (SELECT ... bob)`.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, also don't underestimate the power of the SQL optimizer; you might find that `SELECT Event where UserID IN (SELECT ... bob)` gets planned and executed the same as `SELECT Event JOIN USER ON .. WHERE bob` - take a look at the query plans for the various options